# how to perform the following operation using numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
list_2 = [2,4]
list_index = 0
list_3 = [0]*(len(list_1)+len(list_2))
for index in range(6):
      if index in list_2:
           list_3[index] = -1
      else:
           list_3[index] = list_1[list_index]
           list_index += 1
```

Is there a way to perform the above operation using numpy arrays
The output of the above code is [1,2,-1,3,-1,4]

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. First create an empty array(say `arr`) using [`numpy.zeros`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html). Now using the items in `list_2` as indices assign -1 to `arr` and then find the items whose values are not equal to -1 or is equal to 0 and and assign the items of `list_1` to it.

```
>>> list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list_2 = [2,4]
>>> arr = np.zeros(len(list_1)+len(list_2))
>>> arr[list_2] = -1
>>> arr[arr!=-1] = list_1
>>> arr
array([ 1.,  2., -1.,  3., -1.,  4.])
```